# why textbox automatically clears in button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my login.aspx page,when I click the submit button the first textbox's value is retained..the second textbox (password field) automatically clears,so im unable to enter into the homepage.Even if i close the window and open again its not working.Why the textbox clears in button click?
this is my code:
aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="251px" Style="z-index: 100; left: 349px;
            position: absolute; top: 320px" Width="415px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="z-index: 100; left: 126px; position: absolute;
            top: 89px" Text="USERNAME:" ForeColor="#C04000"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Style="z-index: 102; left: 126px; position: absolute;
            top: 136px" Text="PASSWORD:" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" ForeColor="#C04000"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Style="z-index: 105; left: 151px;
                position: absolute; top: 166px" Text="INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD" Visible="False"
                Width="314px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                ErrorMessage="FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY" Style="z-index: 106; left: 423px; position: absolute;
                top: 90px" Width="227px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                ErrorMessage="FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY" Style="z-index: 107; left: 424px; position: absolute;
                top: 135px" Width="214px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                ErrorMessage="ENTER ONLY CHARACTERS(MIN2)" Height="1px" Style="z-index: 108; left: 415px;
                position: absolute; top: 88px" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z\s]{2,15}$" Width="228px"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="#8080FF" Style="z-index: 109;
                left: 204px; position: absolute; top: -62px" Text="LOGIN " Width="109px"></asp:Label>

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="z-index: 101; left: 241px; position: absolute;
            top: 89px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Style="z-index: 101; left: 242px; position: absolute;
            top: 132px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" Style="z-index: 101; left: 179px; position: absolute;
            top: 195px" onclick="Button1_Click"/>

        </asp:Panel>
```

aspx.cs page:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pwd = TextBox2.Text;
        TextBox2.Attributes.Add("value", pwd);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String un = null;
            String pw = null;
            string con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(con1);

            con.Open(); //connection must be openned
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from admin", con); // creating query command
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // executes query
            while (reader.Read()) // if can read row from database
            {
                un = reader[0].ToString();
                pw = reader[1].ToString();
                // Get column 1 and column 3 value and print
            }
            if (un.Equals(TextBox1.Text) && (pw.Equals(TextBox2.Text)))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/homepage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label3.Visible = true;
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("error"+ex); 
        }
```

when i add this in the page load:

```
string pwd = TextBox2.Text;
TextBox2.Attributes.Add("value", pwd);
```

the textbox value is reatined i think..but,it does not go inside the button click event..

Comment: if (un.Equals(TextBox1.Text) && (pw.Equals(TextBox2.Text)))  so much bracket closing

Comment: Place a brake point in the while loop and check what you get inside 'un' and 'pw'

Comment: the thing even if i place a brake point the control is not going inside the button click itself.,in the browser itself it automatically clears

Comment: @user2605748 check the links i gave in answer

Comment: @user2605748 it must be making postback right or not. Is page load event being hit

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (un.Equals(TextBox1.Text) && (pw.Equals(TextBox2.Text)))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/homepage.aspx");
        }
```

the above code need to be inside the while loop and the code inside the else should be after the while loop

Comment: @Gangadhar,  Why so? can you elaborate

Comment: you need to check the condition inside the loop where you get the values

Comment: there is no column three in the database

Comment: in the code comments you gave "// Get column 1 and column 3 value and print"

Comment: sorry it was by mistake

Answer (score 0):

That's how the password textbox works, if you need to retain the value then store in Viewstate or Session or do what I do and put the username and password on the last step before submitting the form.

```
private string Password
{
    get
    {        
        string rv = "";
        if(ViewState["Password"] != null)
        {
            rv = ViewState["Password"].ToString();
        }
        return rv;            

    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Password"] = value;
    }
}


//on button click
this.Password =  this.PasswordTextBox.Text
```

Comment: It's a security restriction, you cannot set a password textbox in code this.passwordtextbox.text ="123" and it does not restore the value after postback.

Comment: Are you using forms authentication because your code is not going to work, you need to set the FormsAuthentication ticket and do a correct login, you should look into using the MembershipProvider.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("value", TextBox1.Text);
TextBox2.Attributes.Add("value", TextBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work without setting the FormsAuthentication ticket.

You need to look at this code : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx